# Mobile phone support for http progressive download and other streaming protocols.

Tags: mobile, video, video-streaming, html5-video

Do most modernish versions of Samsung Bada OS, Nokia Symbian, Nokia Series 40, Windows Phone, and Blackberry support http progressive download via their default web browser (and assumedly passing the call onto a media player)?

Essentially, I want to figure out the best combination of video streaming protocols to use to reach the maximum of users on these devices (if a user clicks on a link to play video via a web browser). I can't find any documentation about whether the media players support http progressive download, although it seems ridiculous that they wouldn't. Some of the latest versions of these OSs support HTML5... which means they can in theory play video within the browser.